# How to check if a date range in my dataframe overlaps with any (ID-specific) range in another dataframe

Tags: r, date, match

I have 2 dataframes (DFs) that each contain identifiers and date ranges. In both DFs there can be numerous date ranges associated with each ID.

What I want to do is select the rows from the first DF (DF.A) for which there is an overlapping interval of any length, in the second DF (DF.B).

```
df.A <- data.frame("ID" =       c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
                   "Start.A" =  c("2019-01-01", "2019-03-15", "2019-06-10", "2017-01-01", "2015-05-10", "2015-05-15"),
                   "End.A" =    c("2019-01-31", "2019-04-15", "2019-07-09", "2017-01-31", "2015-06-10", "2015-06-02"))


df.B <- data.frame("ID" =       c(1,1,1,3,3),
                   "Start.B" =  c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2015-06-01", "2015-07-01"),
                   "End.B" =    c("2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-31", "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31"))
```

Dataframe A:

```
ID       Start.A       End.A
1        2019-01-01    2019-01-31 
1        2019-03-15    2019-04-15 
1        2019-06-10    2019-07-09
2        2017-01-01    2017-01-31
3        2015-05-10    2015-06-10
3        2015-05-15    2015-06-02
```

Dataframe B:

```
ID       Start.B       End.B
1        2019-01-01    2019-01-31
1        2019-02-01    2019-02-28
1        2019-03-01    2019-03-31
3        2015-06-01    2015-06-30
3        2015-07-01    2015-07-31
```

Would I would like as my output is:

```
ID       Start.A       End.A
1        2019-01-01    2019-01-31 
1        2019-03-15    2019-04-15 
3        2015-05-10    2015-06-10
3        2015-05-15    2015-06-02
```

I think I would be able to do this without a problem if I had a one to one match but, as I mentioned, in both DFs there are numerous observations for each ID. I've tried my hand at trying to apply lubridate's interval but I'm struggling with how to how to look for overlaps while dealing with the added complexity of having to look up all corresponding IDs in DF.B for a potential match.

This is a very large dataset (>5 million observations in DF.A and >2 million in DF.B) so speed is crucial. Any recommendations to transform the data to make this operation as fast as possible would also be appreciated.

If helpful: For a given ID, DF.A can have observations that overlap with other observations in DF.A (e.g. ID 3 in the toy example above). Contrarily, there can be no overlaps between the DF.B intervals.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
library(data.table)
df.A <- data.table("ID" =       c(1,1,1,2,3,3),
                   "Start.A" =  c("2019-01-01", "2019-03-15", "2019-06-10", "2017-01-01", "2015-05-10", "2015-05-15"),
                   "End.A" =    c("2019-01-31", "2019-04-15", "2019-07-09", "2017-01-31", "2015-06-10", "2015-06-02"))


df.B <- data.table("ID" =       c(1,1,1,3,3),
                   "Start.B" =  c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2015-06-01", "2015-07-01"),
                   "End.B" =    c("2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-31", "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31"))
```

And

```
DF = merge(df.A, df.B , by ='ID',allow.cartesian = TRUE)

DF$SEQ_DATE.A = apply(DF[,c('Start.A','End.A'), with=F],1, function(x){paste(x,collapse = ',')})

DF$SEQ_DATE.A = unlist(lapply(strsplit(DF$SEQ_DATE.A,','),function(x){
  out = seq(as.Date(x[1]),as.Date(x[2]),by = 'day')
  out = paste(out, collapse = '|')
  return(out)
}
))

DF$SEQ_DATE.B = apply(DF[,c('Start.B','End.B'), with=F],1, function(x){paste(x,collapse = ',')})

DF$SEQ_DATE.B = unlist(lapply(strsplit(DF$SEQ_DATE.B,','),function(x){
  out = seq(as.Date(x[1]),as.Date(x[2]),by = 'day')
  out = paste(out, collapse = '|')
  return(out)
}
))

DF$Result= apply(DF[,c('SEQ_DATE.A','SEQ_DATE.B'), with = F], 1, function(x){grepl(x[1],x[2])})
```

And the result is shown below :

```
> DF[,-c('SEQ_DATE.A','SEQ_DATE.B'), with =F][Result == 'TRUE']

   ID    Start.A      End.A    Start.B      End.B Result
1:  1 2019-01-01 2019-01-31 2019-01-01 2019-01-31   TRUE
2:  1 2019-03-15 2019-04-15 2019-03-01 2019-03-31   TRUE
3:  3 2015-05-10 2015-06-10 2015-06-01 2015-06-30   TRUE
4:  3 2015-05-15 2015-06-02 2015-06-01 2015-06-30   TRUE
```